# Wait function which has promise method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to wait constructor() which has async method handled by `Promise`

What I want to do is waiting two async method in constructor, and then wait constructor itself.

However my code shows the error `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: resolve is not defined`

What is the best practices for this purpose??

```
class MyClass{
    constructor(){

        var p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: api1
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    resolve();
                }
            });
        });
        var p2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: api2
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    resolve();
                }
            });
        });
        Promise.all([p1,p2]).then(function(value){
            console.log("finish");
            resolve(); // this shows error.
        });
    }    
}

$(function() {
    var temp = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        var myClass = new MyClass();
    });
    temp.then(function (value) {
        console.log("finish all");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A constructor will always run synchronously. In addition to that, you don't want the explicit Promise construction anti-pattern, so you wouldn't want to call `resolve` inside a `Promise.all` anyway. The `Promise.all([p1,p2])` will be a Promise that resolves when both `p1` and `p2` have resolved, so assign that a property to the instance, and call `.then` on that property. Change

```
Promise.all([p1,p2]).then(function(value){
  // ...
});
```

to

```
this.apiPromises = Promise.all([p1,p2]);
```

and, when constructing the instance:

```
$(function() {
    const myInstance = new MyClass();
    myInstance.apiPromises
    .then(function (value) {
        console.log("finish all");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        // handle errors
    });
});
```

(If you aren't calling either of the `resolve`s of with anything in `p1` or `p2`, best to delete the `value` parameter, since it holds no useful information)

`$.ajax` returns a thenable already, so you don't need to call `new Promise` when creating the `p1` and `p2`s:

```
var p1 = $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: api1, // remember to put commas after values in an object to avoid a SyntaxError
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  }
});
var p2 = $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: api2, // remember to put commas after values in an object to avoid a SyntaxError
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  }
});
```

(using the above will also properly reject the `Promise.all` when an error occurs)

Comment: Thank you very much !! it works well. And $.ajax doesn't need promise is new hint for me. maybe I might change many points in my past works....